# Flask 2.3 deprecated before_request decorerator

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I am using flask security and sqlalchemy to store user credentials
but unfortunately flask 2.3 does not suppport `security = Security(app, user_datastore)`
any assistance would be appreicated.

I tried the following
`user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role) security = Security(app, user_datastore)`
but i get
`AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'before_first_request'. Did you mean: '_got_first_request'?`
when i disable the `security = Security(app, user_datastore)`, it works fine but it will not store the first time login credentials to database

Answer (score 2):

The package Flask-Security is no longer maintained - there are a couple options-  I maintain Flask-Security-Too which started from Flask-Security 3.0 and has had many improvements and is compatible with latest Flask/Werkzeug.

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.3.x. You can remove the decorator @before_first_request and move the code to out of function. It should work.